# How to call startActivityForResult inside an adapter extending BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on an Activity named DashboardActivity which contain two tabs namely SocialFragmentTab and ProfessionalFragmentTab. Both are Fragments here.In ProfesionalFragmentTab i am having a list view which is populated by a custom adapter extending BaseAdapter.Inside ProfesionalFragmentTab ,"Apply" button is there.On clicking apply buttton ,a dialog is opened which contains some information .It also contains a button "Select Latest Resume" .On clicking this button i want to select resume(A text file) from my android phone.I am getting some problem in using startActivityForResult() here.
Plz check the files.I am not able to browse file on clicking "Select Latest Resume button"

FeedListProfessionalTimelineAdapter.java

```
public class FeedListProfessionalTimelineAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<FeedItemProfessionalTimeline> listProfessionalTimeline;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    private static final int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 1;

    public FeedListProfessionalTimelineAdapter(Context context, List<FeedItemProfessionalTimeline> listProfessionalTimeline) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listProfessionalTimeline = listProfessionalTimeline;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listProfessionalTimeline.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listProfessionalTimeline.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item_professional_tab_timeline, parent, false);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        //Getting the views
        TextView companyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCompanyName);
        TextView jobCategory = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtJobCategory);
        TextView timeStamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeStampPost);
        TextView postName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postName);
        TextView jobLocation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.jobLocation);
        TextView noOfPositions = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.noOfPositions);
        TextView jobDescriptions = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.jobDescription);
        Button apply = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnApply);
        Button share = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnShare);
        // On clicking apply button
        apply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // A dialog will be opened that will cllow the user to apply for the job
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder;
                AlertDialog alertDialog;
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()); // we are using v.getContext here because View v is a part of Fragment that is shown through BaseAdapter inside Fragment
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Apply for JOB");
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_apply_job, parent, false);
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);
                alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
                // Getting Button resume
                Button resumeBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnResume);
                resumeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        intent.setType("file/*");
                        Context context = v.getContext();
                        ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);                    }
                    });

                }

            });



            FeedItemProfessionalTimeline item = listProfessionalTimeline.get(position);
            //Getting values from List
            String companyNam = item.getCompanyName();
            String jobCat = item.getJobCategory();
            Log.e("job category", jobCat);
            String date_time = item.getDate_time();
            String jobTitle = item.getJobTitle();
            //To make job title underline
            String htmlJobTitle = "<u>" + jobTitle + "</u>";
            String jobLocatn = item.getJobLocation();
            String positions = item.getPositions();
            String positionsOpen = "Positions open : " + positions;
            String jobInfo = item.getJobInfo();

            //Setting values to the views
            String postedJob = companyName + " posted a job under " + jobCategory + " category ";
            Log.e("posted job", postedJob);
            companyName.setText(companyNam); // Setting Company name
            jobCategory.setText(jobCat); // Setting job category
            timeStamp.setText(date_time);//Setting timestamp
            postName.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlJobTitle)); //Setting post name
            jobLocation.setText(jobLocatn); // Setting job location
            noOfPositions.setText(positionsOpen);//Setting number of positions
            jobDescriptions.setText(jobInfo);
            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Remove this line `Context context = v.getContext();`

Comment: you are already have the context in constructor so just use that and in ((Activity)context) change Activity to your Activity where you have intialized this adapter. And write onActivityResult in that Activity.

Comment: Thanks Raghavendra.I have initialized the adapter in a fragment named  ProfessionalFragmentTab .How can i use startActivityResult and onActivityResult here for this fragment.

Comment: **Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()** -- is this line displaying toast when you click on apply button inside any list row?

Comment: Droidwala, yes this line is displaying toast.

Comment: i am able to select file from my mobile.But i want to know the name of file selected which is to be set inside a textView,I know this is concerned with onActivityResult .Please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this because you are already having context on the top:

```
 resumeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("file/*");
                    //Context context=v.getContext();
                    ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);                    }
                });

            }

        });
```